# Editing related list while cloning record

Tags: clone

I am trying to Clone account detail page with contact related list using Custom button which redirects to VF page.I am able to clone detail page with contact related list,but On clicking 'Add row' button,expected output is to display New row for Contact Name.This should happen on every click of button.On every click,a new row should be displayed.

[image]

VF page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="AccountClone" tabStyle="Account">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:pageBlock>
            <apex:sectionHeader title="AccountClone"/>
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Account Detail">
                <apex:inputField value="{!AccountNew.Name}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!ContactList}" var="Contacts" columns="1" id="contacttable" >
                <apex:column headerValue="Name">
                    <apex:inputfield value="{!Contacts.lastName}" />
                </apex:column>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
            <apex:commandButton value="save clone" action="{!clonerelatedlist}" />
            <apex:commandButton value="add row" action="{!addRow}" reRender="contacttable"/>
            </apex:pageBlock>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Extension code:

```
public with sharing class AccountClone {

  public ID AccountId {get;set;} 

  public Account AccountOld {get;set;}

  public Account AccountNew {get;set;}

  public List<Contact> ContactList {get;set;}

  public Contact ContactNew {get;set;}

  public List<Contact> ContactListNew = new List<Contact>();

  public AccountClone(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

    accountID=Apexpages.CurrentPage().getParameters().get('id');

    clonewithcontact();

  }

  public void clonewithcontact(){

    AccountOld = [Select Name,(Select lastName from contacts) from Account where ID=:accountID];

    AccountNew =AccountOld.clone(false,false,false,false);

    ContactList= new List<Contact>();

    ContactList.addALL(AccountOld.Contacts);

  }

  //function to create contact

  public void addRow(){

    contact con = new contact();

    ContactList.add(con);

  }

  public pageReference clonerelatedlist(){

    Database.insert(AccountNew);


    for(Contact c: ContactList){

      ContactNew =c.clone();

      ContactNew.AccountId=AccountNew.Id;

      ContactListNew.add(ContactNew);
    }

    insert ContactListNew;

    pageReference pg = new pageReference('/'+AccountNew.Id);

    pg.setRedirect(True);

    return pg;
  }

}
```

Comment: when does `addRow()` get invoked? In what order to the controller's actionmethods get invoked?

Comment: it will be called on clicking a button Addrow which is defined in VF page

Comment: @devsfdc Thanks for adding the Visualforce to your question! There's still additional information that is needed before I (or others) can give you a correct solution. Please edit your question to include what you expect to see in the `pageBlockTable` for the `Contacts` when you first navigate to the Visualforce page, and what you expect to see in the `pageBlockTable` after clicking the `Add Row` button.

Comment: Derek,added information about expected result.I hope,this will be good

Answer (score 1):

<del>Your problem here is that the `Contact` record you're creating in `addRow()` is never being related to your new (cloned) Account.</del>

`cloneRelatedList()` goes through the existing `Contacts`, clones them, and then re-parents them. That part is correct. However, you're only looping through `ContactList` to re-parent, and not `ContactListNew` (which is where you're putting the new `Contact` created by `addRow()`.)

A simple change to make this work the way you're expecting it to would be to separate the cloning and re-parenting of existing `Contacts` into two loops like this.

.

```
public pageReference clonerelatedlist(){

  Database.insert(AccountNew);

  for(Contact c: ContactList){
    ContactNew =c.clone();    
    ContactListNew.add(ContactNew);
  }

  for(Contact c : ContactListNew){
    c.AccountId=AccountNew.Id;
  }

  insert ContactListNew;

  pageReference pg = new pageReference('/'+AccountNew.Id);

  pg.setRedirect(True);

  return pg;
}
```

**+edit:**

While my previous answer solved one of the issues with the provided code, it didn't answer the text of the amended question.

The reason why `addRow()` isn't adding a row to your `<apex:pageBlockTable>` is because you are attempting to give it `Accounts.Contacts`, which is the list of contacts from the `Account` that you're going to clone, rather than the `ContactListNew` variable that `addRow()` is adding your new `Contact` to.

That said, I still don't think that you've identified all of the issues (or the core issue) that you're facing, and because of that, I don't think your code is complete.

`addRow()` simply creates a new `Contact` records, and adds it to a list. Nowhere in your provided code are you setting the Contact's `LastName`. As is, you'll be seeing rows being added to your table, but they'll be blank rows.

I'm afraid that I can't provide much more help with what you've provided us thus far.

Comment: Derek: Yes,that is fine.What I want is when I click on 'Addrow' button(Button is defined in VF page),addrow() function will be called and it should display a row of Contact with 'Name'(this is also done in VF page)

Comment: @devsfdc, your comment isn't very clear. I think I can piece together what you're really asking (which is a bit different from what you initially asked)...but it would be very helpful if you would edit your question to include your Visualforce page, and perhaps a screenshot of what your page is displaying versus what you want your page to display.

Comment: I have added VF code and Screenshot of the current output

Comment: I was able to add a new row,Thanks for help Derek.But still it is not displaying new row on each click on Button.
And the reason,I have not mentioned 'lastname' in code as currently, My objective was simply to add a new row for contact.

Comment: Finally,I got it.I have edited the code.